# jQuery UI dialogs and aria-controls

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, accessibility, wai-aria

Would using [`aria-controls`](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-controls) on a button to reference a jQuery UI dialog element that it opens be appropriate usage of ARIA?

I already notice that jQuery UI automatically wraps the `div` in another **separate** `div` that has `role=dialog` and `aria-labelledby` with the title of the dialog. I've seen `aria-controls` on relationships between tab links and tab panels as well as buttons and form elements (inputs, dropdowns, etc) but not between buttons and dialog boxes.

Here is a code example to demonstrate what I'm asking about:

```js
$('button[aria-controls$="-dialog"]').on('click', function() {
  var $dialog = $('#' + $(this).attr('aria-controls'));
  $dialog.dialog('open');
});

$('.jqui-dialog').dialog({
  modal: true,
  autoOpen: false
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src=https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js></script>
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href=https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/dot-luv/jquery-ui.css>

<button type=button aria-controls=add-new-item-dialog>
  Add new item
</button>

<div id=add-new-item-dialog class=jqui-dialog title='Add new item'>
  <p>A form here.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using [aria-controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-controls) for an element role [button](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#button) is allowed per the ARIA spec and your use case makes sense. It would be up to the user agent/assistive technology to provide whatever behavior it deems appropriate for this relationship (with JAWS you can use [INSERT-ALT-M](https://www.freedomscientific.com/Content/Documents/Other/JAWS-ARIA-Support.doc) to navigate to the controlled element. If the dialog is not modal and the button toggles it, this provides useful navigational support. If the dialog is modal, it does not add much to the user experience).

What will improve the user experience in your case is if you `aria-haspopup="true"` to indicate that the button will spawn a popup. This will then be announced to screen reader users.

Here Leonie Watson (ARIA WG member) specifically uses a button as an example for ARIA controls and talks about how screen readers currently (as of the writing) support it http://tink.uk/using-the-aria-controls-attribute/

Comment: The main aspect of the question was to know if we can reference a node marked as a jQuery ui-dialog with the `aria-controls` attribute (as, for instance, this would target the inner element, and not the wrapping dialog). But you make a point mentioning `aria-haspopup`, as this is the correct way to avoid the problem with `aria-controls` in this context.

Answer (score 0):

**In the jQuery current implementation, I don't think it's appropriate.**

According to the ARIA documentation for "aria-controls"
http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-controls

> Identifies the element (or elements) whose contents or presence are controlled by the current element. See related aria-owns.

What does this mean?

This can be used for buttons which **control** a video, a slider, a tab panel, or whatever needs to be **controlled**.

When you focus such button, JAWS announces "Use Jaws key + alt + m to move to the controlled element". So if the element has `display:none`, it won't work. If you want to control the "presence" of an element you'll have to target a parent element or play with visibility/z-index CSS attributes.

The expected result is that the screen reader can lead you to the affected element, without requiring that you pressed the button.

In your case, you have, when the page loads, an `ui-dialog` with the css property `display: none`. So when the screenreader will announce that the button can affect another element, you won't be able to jump to it unless you effectively press it before as the element is not already in the visual flow.

**TL;DR: the `aria-controls` attribute indicates which element can be affected by a control. The screen reader will give you a quick access to that element (without requiring you to effectively press the control itself). This requires that the visual focus could be moved to the targeted element.**

Comment: A button that causes a dialog to popup, certainly controls the presence of that dialog. The exact same thing can be said of a tab and the tab-panel that is part of a tablist. If a tab can control the tabpanel, why not a button and a dialog (inparticular if the dialog is not modal and the button a toggle button)?

Comment: @unobf You can perfectly use a button to open a dialog, and use the `aria-controls` attribute as long as the dialog is in the current visual flow of the page. You have to use a different implementation (like using `z-index`, `visibility:hidden`). When you use `display:none` like in the specific case of this question, where the user uses jQuery UI dialog, JAWS won't be able to target the controlled element unless the user previously pressed the button (which is not the expected behavior).

Comment: precisely the same thing would happen with the tab controls for the tabs that are not selected in a tabpanel. display:none has nothing to do with aria-controls whatsoever. See this implementation http://oaa-accessibility.org/example/34/ your tl;dr is absolute hogswash.

Comment: This implementation is a perfect illustration of what I am saying. Please use a screen reader and see the benefit of `aria-controls` here. None. Nothing. Niet. Nada. Zero. My god, we are working for people using screen reader, do not give me such bad example of tab panel (I expect the enter key to work when the visual focus is over a tab). I really respect your work and truly like many of your interventions here, but I have too much respect for people to use aria just for decorative purpose.

Comment: That is probably a bug in the implementation, it does not invalidate the rest of the implementation though. Also, it is not my implementation but has involved Rich Schwerdtfeger - the person who invented ARIA http://www.openajax.org/member/wiki/Accessibility#Participating_Companies_and_Organizations

Comment: See the latest modification I made to my answer

Comment: Yes Leonie says it right "When a User Agent (UA) supports aria-controls, it makes it possible for focus to be moved from the current element directly to the element it controls.". Impossible to move the focus to an element with `display:none`. And this is confirmed by this implementation. Are we definitely ok?